# Outlook For CiviCRM - How to bypass activity confirmation dialog?

Tags: extension

**Background:** When *Outlook For CiviCRM* is properly installed, configured and enabled, a confirmation dialog titled *Confirm Activity* appers for every email that is going to be sent. We would like very much to use this extension, but in our daily business can't afford this extra step and the delay caused by it.

**Question:** Is there a way to setup a default confirmation for this *Confirm Activity* dialog?

Answer (score 3):

Outlook-CiviCRM [documentation](https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.outlookapi/blob/master/README.md) says that the confirm dialog box can be turned off through UI.

```
Prompt for All emails?: If this setting is enabled - While sending emails, you would always be asked whether you want to record this email in CiviCRM (A small pop up confirmation box would appear). If you don't want to be asked every time and just want to record every email you send, turn this setting off
```

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: This option **won't** turn off the Confirm Activity dialog. When enabled, it will just display an Yes-No-Box to ask whether you want to record the email in CiviCRM at all or not. After clicking on Yes, the Confirm Activity dialog will appear.